# potential race when subclassing std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11

From a design angle, it may seem desirable to build subclasses of `std::thread` — such a class *is-a* thread, but adds special functionality, the thread function can be a private member and use completely encapsulated data, you can control access/interactions and provide locking / sync if necessary, it is RAII (the thread either runs or it blows up)...

*However....*

Reading the [documentation on Cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), there is the provision that "the completion of the invocation of the constructor *synchronizes-with* (as defined in [std::memory_order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)) the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f` on the new thread of execution".

Is my conclusion correct that *in theory* this introduces all kinds of funny (undefined) behaviour, since the end of "invocation of the `std::thread` constructor" is when the initialisation of the derived class commences?

To give an educational example:

```
class MyThread : public std::thread {

  std::unique_ptr<Something> thing;

  void threadOp() {
    thing.reset(new Something{});
    // cool stuff here...
  }

public:
  MyThread()
    : std::thread{ &MyThread::threadOp, this}
    { }
};
```

Concurrency is when "things *can happen*" — so in theory the thread calling the MyThread ctor could be preempted, the thread function starts in the new thread and allocates, and then the default-ctor of the member field `thing` (which is implicitly called after the base class ctor) will stomp in, possibly not even see the effect of the allocation yet and initialise to `nullptr`, and so on...

Is this reasoning valid, or am I misinterpreting something?

It should be mentioned though, that in practice the OS scheduler has a considerable latency. In measurements with `std::system_clock` under various conditions (under Linux), I have never seen a time point at the start of the thread function, which is not at least 100µs later (usually its much more like 400µs) than a time point captured in the main thread after construction of the whole compound. Which, of course does in no way disprove the theoretical possibility of a race...

#### Question

- is the above theoretic reasoining correct?
- what would be a practical situation like where such a race could actually be observed?

Comment: Most STL classes are not designed to be inherited from (ie, no virtual members/destructors, etc). Consider using encapsulation instead of inheritance, that way you have more control over when you start the thread running once you are actually ready for it to run.

Comment: Inheriting from a thread class is such a Java thing to do. Don't do it in C++.

Comment: @etienne-de-martel choosing some design is not a matter of principle, but a matter trade-off and argument. I'd seriously caution not to reject some option just because "it is soo XYZ"

Comment: Another point worth mentioninng: "virtual" and "inheritance" are two things in C++ (and this is good). Lots of valid designs where you use inheritance without any VTable, esp. in template heavy code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is worse than you describe.

If the thread starts executing `threadOp` before the constructor initialized the `thing` object its internal values could potentially be anything and you are executing a `reset()` method (so you are well into undefined behavior here).

But also looking practically, the `reset()` methods will call delete on what is currently stored the unique_ptr which is currently some random memory before assigning the value.

Then when the constructor eventually gets around to initializing the `thing` it will overwrite any value with `nullptr` thus leaking your memory.

So releasing random memory followed by leaking memory.

> what would be a practical situation like where such a race could actually be observed?

Its not about `if` its simply about `when` run it enough times its going to happen. Will it happen in our lifetimes no idea but it will eventually happen.

The solution is to start the new thread of execution in the body of the constructor after all the members have been initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is correct. This is undefined behavior.

It is not difficult to fix this specific issue:

```
  MyThread()
  {
      std::thread::operator=(std::thread{ &MyThread::threadOp, this});
  }
```

There are still a number of design issues here, overall, but at least this addresses this specific failure case.

Comment: I'm not sure this problem can be fixed... It will strike at destruction time too: `thing` will get destroyed while `thread` is still alive. That might be a disaster if the thread has been detached and still running.

Comment: This is why I wrote "there are still a number of design issues here", @IgorG, my answer was strictly about what was asked.

Comment: lots of issues and possible races at destruction time indeed; I left this aspect out deliberately (to keep focussed). Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

By my understanding, your reasoning is correct.

The standard specifies that base class constructors are called before any members of the derived class are initialised, and that is before the body/block of the derived constructor is entered.   In your case, the order is then `std::thread`s constructor, then your member thing will be default-constructed, then the body of `MyThread`s constructor is reached.

`std::thread`s constructor creates the thread of execution and starts the thread running which executes the function you have called, which may modify the member `thing` before `thing` is initialised.   That is undefined behaviour.

That expresses things slightly differently than you have (and possibly omits some nuances) but comes to the same conclusion.

Also, as noted by Remy Lebeau in a comment below your question, `std::thread` (like most classes in the standard library) is not designed to be used as a base class - no virtual functions, no virtual destructor, etc,

Because of this, it is preferable to use aggregation rather than inheritance - i.e. the `std::thread` a *member* of your class.  The order in which non-static members are declared in the class definition allows you to control the order in which members are initialised (and their constructors called).   This will work since the constructor of `MyThread` can refer to - and call - `MyThread`s member functions, directly or indirectly.

It would also (mostly) be inadvisable to derive classes from `MyThread`.

Comment: Good point concerning classes derived from `MyThread` — in fact that is where the problem becomes actually relevant in practice. I've just used the `MyThread` example here to keep the dicussion focussed